# How the `onException` behaves

Tags: haskell, exception

`finally` and `onException` are two functions from the module `Control.Exception`, which have the same signature but behave differently. 
 [Here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:onException) is the document. 
For `finally`, it says:

```
finally 
:: IO a  -- computation to run first
-> IO b  -- computation to run afterward (even if an exception was raised)
-> IO a
```

, while for `onException`, it says:

> Like `finally`, but only performs the final action if there was an
>   exception raised by the computation.

So I do the following test:

```
ghci> finally (return $ div 4 2) (putStrLn "Oops!")
Oops!
2
ghci> finally (return $ div 4 0) (putStrLn "Oops!")
Oops!
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

which acts as expected.

However, `onException` does not:

```
ghci> onException (return $ div 4 2) (putStrLn "Oops!")
2
ghci> onException (return $ div 4 0) (putStrLn "Oops!")  -- does not act as expected
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

As describe above, `onException` only performs the final action if an exception was raised, but the example above shows that `onException` does not perform the final action, i.e. `putStrLn "Oops!"` when an exception raised.

After checking the [source code](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.11.1.0/src/Control.Exception.Base.html#onException) for `onException`, I try the test as follow:

```
ghci> throwIO (SomeException DivideByZero) `catch` \e -> do {_ <- putStrLn "Oops!"; throwIO (e :: SomeException)}
Oops!
*** Exception: divide by zero
ghci> onException (throwIO (SomeException DivideByZero)) (putStrLn "Oops!")
Oops!
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

As can be seen, when an exception raised explicitly, the final action was performed.

So the question is `return $ div 4 0` really throws an exception, but **why `onException (return $ div 4 0) (putStrLn "Oops!")` does not perform the final action `putStrLn "Oops!"`? What am I missing? And how the exception was performed?**

```
ghci> throwIO (SomeException DivideByZero)
*** Exception: divide by zero
ghci> (return $ div 4 0) :: IO Int
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You’ve been bitten by lazy evaluation.**

One of the key guarantees of `throwIO` is that it guarantees *when* the exception will be raised with respect to the execution of other `IO` actions. From [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO):

> Although `throwIO` has a type that is an instance of the type of `throw`, the two functions are subtly different:
>
> ```
> throw e   `seq` x  ===> throw e
> throwIO e `seq` x  ===> x
> ```
>
> The first example will cause the exception `e` to be raised, whereas the second one won't. In fact, `throwIO` will only cause an exception to be raised when it is used within the `IO` monad. The `throwIO` variant should be used in preference to throw to raise an exception within the `IO` monad because it guarantees ordering with respect to other `IO` operations, whereas `throw` does not.

This means that, when the `throwIO e` action is executed (not merely evaluated!) as a part of the execution of the action produced by `onException`, it is guaranteed to actually raise an exception. Since the exception is raised within the dynamic extent of the execution of the exception handler, the exception is detected, and the handler function is executed.

However, when you write `return e`, the action it produces does *not* evaluate `e` to WHNF when it is executed, and `e` is only evaluated if/when the action’s result is itself evaluated. By the time the `div 4 0` expression is forced by GHCi by `show`ing the action’s result, control has left the dynamic extent of the execution of `onException`, and the handler it installed is no longer on the stack. The exception is raised, but it is raised too late.

To get the behavior you want, it’s critical to ensure you evaluate `div 4 0` as a part of your action’s execution, and not a moment before or after. This is what [the `evaluate` function from `Control.Exception`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate) is for. It evaluates its argument to WHNF as a part of the execution of the `IO` action itself, guaranteeing that any exceptions raised as part of that evaluation will be detected by a surrounding exception handler:

```
ghci> onException (evaluate $ div 4 0) (putStrLn "Oops!")
Oops!
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

The moral: when handling exceptions in Haskell, be very careful about when things are evaluated to ensure the exception is raised within the dynamic extent of your exception handler and is not deferred due to lazy evaluation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves my puzzle, and it seems a long way to learn the exception control in Haskell.