# When is `after` called?

Tags: haskell

There is a good known function - `bracket`:

```hs
bracket
        :: IO a         -- ^ computation to run first (\"acquire resource\")
        -> (a -> IO b)  -- ^ computation to run last (\"release resource\")
        -> (a -> IO c)  -- ^ computation to run in-between
        -> IO c         -- returns the value from the in-between computation
bracket before after thing =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a <- before
    r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after a
    _ <- after a
    return r
```

I see two calls of `after`: once on an exception, the second time - `_ <- after a` - in all cases (with exception/without exception). I call this:

```hs
bracket (pure 1) (\a -> print a >> pure a) (\a -> head [])
```

And `print` happens only once. Then why, with 2 `after`s? How does it work at all?

Could somebody explain in details how this snippet:

```hs
r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after a
_ <- after a
```

work exactly?

ps. I tried bang (`!..`) patterns, and nothing changed, it seems it is not about lazy evaluation...

**EDIT: experiment with own (more specific logic) implementation:**

```hs
mybracket
        :: IO a                    -- ^computation to run first (\"acquire resource\")
        -> (Maybe c -> a -> IO c)  -- ^computation to run last (\"release resource\")
        -> (a -> IO c)             -- ^computation to run in-between
        -> IO c                    -- returns the value from the in-between computation
mybracket before after thing =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a <- before
    r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after Nothing a
    r1 <- after (Just r) a
    return r1
```

Can I be sure that `mybracket` will call `after` just once - for exception in `thing` and when no any exceptions, in both cases?

Comment: I guess when there is an exception the next line is not executed. `bracket`, `finally`, `onException` and other variants will re-raise the exception.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088100/how-the-onexception-behaves

Comment: @RuudHelderman I tried `Control.Exception.bracket (pure 1) (\a -> print "!" >> pure a) (\a -> evaluate $ head [])` and own definition of the `bracket` with bangs in all variables, but `print` is executing just once. Maybe it's really something related to lazy evaluation, but TBH I don't see where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`onException` re-throws the exception.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:onException) So in this snippet,

```
                                 -- if
                                 -- `action` returns normally | `action` throws an exception
                                 -- then
r <- action `onException` after  -- this `after` doesn't run  | this `after` runs 
_ <- after                       -- that `after` runs         | that `after` doesn't run
...
```

... either `action` succeeds, then the  `` `onException` after `` is ignored and only `_ <- after` runs. Or `action` throws an exception, then `` after `onException` after `` re-throws the exception after running `after`, and `_ <- after` doesn't run.